# Storage algorithms for Decentralized Storage System

Tags: storage, swarm, storj, erasure-codes

I am working on a project to build a decentralized storage system compatible with Ethereum blockchain. I am confused between Erasure coding and Proof-of-Replication to use for data redundancy storage algorithms. I know that erasure coding provides storage efficiency and less storage overhead whereas PoRep provides less computational overhead & easy to implement, less complex. Can anyone explain which algorithm would be better suited if I want to build storage system using Ethereum as its blockchain? Also please let me know some existing storage systems that uses Ethereum blockchain(eg. Swarm, Storj) so that I can take a reference from them.
Thank you in advance!